# How difficult is it to move an asp.net / sql setup over to amazon web services?

Tags: asp.net, sql, amazon-web-services

I'm not a developer, far from it, but I'm looking 1) for cost effective server power and 2)on demand scalability.

We're currently hosting our staging site on a vps with cbeyond but we're going to need a much more powerful server when we go live.  so my options are upgrade with cbeyond (very pricy) or migrate.

Before I present to my developer  "lets move to AWS" i want to know the headaches that will be involved and if its even doable.  I dont want to present him with yet another difficult task right before we launch, but we both agree that a more powerful server is needed.

We're running asp.net 3.5 and sql server 2008. Is there a steep learning curve required to move over to AWS (any suggested resources) or can we still run all the famailiar microsoft technology with AWS?

Annotated version:
1) asp.net /sql possible on AWS?
2) headaches presented by this?
3) suggested resources?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean Amazon EC2, right ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean Amazon EC2, right ?

You can create a virtual machine with your webserver, database server and
could host it in the amazon ec2 cloud. You can use Microsoft Azure too.